# Relacionar 3 tabelas em uma linha - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero fazer uma tabela unido informações de 3 tabelas. Essa tabela será ordenada pela data (dia/mês/ano Horas:Minutos) e visualmente falando ficaria assim

[Imagem da tabela](http://prntscr.com/f6u7yr)

Para melhor compreensão vou postar a estrutura dos bancos

tabela: **realation_notes**

*id user_id comments comment_date*

tabela: **historic_attendance**

*id user_id date contato_p contato_e contato_t contato_w contato_m*

tabela: **clients_documents**

*id user_id file_name attachment date*

inicialmente pensei em usar um UNION
ficando mais ou menos assim

```
(SELECT id, user_id, comments, comment_date AS date FROM `realation_notes` 
                                                   WHERE `user_id` = 582)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `historic_attendance` WHERE `user_id` = 582)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `clients_documents` WHERE `user_id` = 582)
ORDER BY date
```

porém esse SQL me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Os comandos SELECT usados têm diferente número de colunas
```

como eu poderia contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION serve para unir conjunto de dados similares vindo de consultas diferentes.

Para relacionar tabelas entre si a partir de uma chave primária/estrangeira é necessário utilizar alguma forma de JOIN tipo:

```
SELECT r.id, r.user_id, r.comments, r.comment_date, h.*, d.*
FROM realation_notes AS r
JOIN historic_attendance AS h ON r.user_id = h.user_id
JOIN clients_documents AS d ON r.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE r.user_id = 582
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

O problema de usares o comando "Union" neste caso é que ele requer o mesmo número de colunas na união das tabelas.

Imagina que tens o seguinte esquema:

tabela A (colA, ColB, ColC)

tabela B (colA, ColD, ColE)

Para fazeres Union das duas tabelas precisas que elas tenham os mesmos campos.
Logo,

select colA, ColB, ColC, null, null from table A
union
select colA, null, null, colD, colE from table B

Podes, se quiseres, usar um alias nos valores Null para os dados ficarem mais "limpos".
Boa sorte!